# appending Key value from one json to other in sequence

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have two JSON objects as below

one.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "testname",
    "phone": 212121,
    "seq" : 1
  },
  {
    "name": "testname1",
    "phone": 2146354564,
    "seq" : 2
  },
  {
    "name": "testname2",
    "phone": 12312,
    "seq" : 3
  },
  {
    "name": "testname1",
    "phone": 211221,
    "seq" : 4
  },
  {
    "name": "testname3",
    "phone": 10218550,
    "seq" : 5
  },
  {
    "name": "1testname",
    "phone": 212121,
    "seq" : 6
  },
  {
    "name": "testname12",
    "phone": 2146354564,
    "seq" : 7
  },
  {
    "name": "testname255",
    "phone": 12312,
    "seq" : 8
  },
  {
    "name": "testname123",
    "phone": 211221,
    "seq" : 9
  },
  {
    "name": "testname2133",
    "phone": 10218550,
    "seq" : 10
  }
]
```

two.json

```
[ {
  "success" : true,
  "created" : true,
  "id" : "123",
  "errors" : [ ]
}, {
  "success" : true,
  "created" : true,
  "id" : "12121",
  "errors" : [ ]
},{
  "success" : false,
  "created" : false,
  "id" : null,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Use one of these records?",
    "fields" : [ ],
    "statusCode" : "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
    "extendedErrorDetails" : null
  } ]
}, {
  "success" : false,
  "created" : false,
  "id" : null,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Use one of these records?",
    "fields" : [ ],
    "statusCode" : "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
    "extendedErrorDetails" : null
  } ]
}, {
  "success" : false,
  "created" : false,
  "id" : null,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Use one of these records?",
    "fields" : [ ],
    "statusCode" : "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
    "extendedErrorDetails" : null
  } ]
}, {
  "success" : false,
  "created" : false,
  "id" : null,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Use one of these records?",
    "fields" : [ ],
    "statusCode" : "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
    "extendedErrorDetails" : null
  } ]
}, {
  "success" : false,
  "created" : false,
  "id" : null,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Use one of these records?",
    "fields" : [ ],
    "statusCode" : "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
    "extendedErrorDetails" : null
  } ]
}, {
  "success" : false,
  "created" : false,
  "id" : null,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Use one of these records?",
    "fields" : [ ],
    "statusCode" : "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
    "extendedErrorDetails" : null
  } ]
}, {
  "success" : false,
  "created" : false,
  "id" : null,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Use one of these records?",
    "fields" : [ ],
    "statusCode" : "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
    "extendedErrorDetails" : null
  } ]
}, {
  "success" : false,
  "created" : false,
  "id" : null,
  "errors" : [ {
    "message" : "Use one of these records?",
    "fields" : [ ],
    "statusCode" : "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
    "extendedErrorDetails" : null
  } ]
} ]
```

I am getting two.json(which is output after some functionality) in the same order as one.json

this is my final output json i want to achieve

final.json

```
[
  {
    "name": "testname",
    "phone": 212121,
    "seq": 1,
    "success": true,
    "created": true,
    "id": "11",
    "errors": []
  },
  {
    "name": "testname1",
    "phone": 2146354564,
    "seq": 2,
    "success": true,
    "created": true,
    "id": "323",
    "errors": []
  },
  {
    "name": "testname2",
    "phone": 12312,
    "seq": 3,
    "success": false,
    "created": false,
    "id": null,
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Use one of these records?",
        "fields": [],
        "statusCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
        "extendedErrorDetails": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "testname1",
    "phone": 211221,
    "seq": 4,
    "success": false,
    "created": false,
    "id": null,
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Use one of these records?",
        "fields": [],
        "statusCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
        "extendedErrorDetails": null,
        "success": false,
        "created": false,
        "id": null,
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "Use one of these records?",
            "fields": [],
            "statusCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
            "extendedErrorDetails": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "testname3",
    "phone": 10218550,
    "seq": 5,
    "success": false,
    "created": false,
    "id": null,
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Use one of these records?",
        "fields": [],
        "statusCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
        "extendedErrorDetails": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "1testname",
    "phone": 212121,
    "seq": 6,
    "success": false,
    "created": false,
    "id": null,
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Use one of these records?",
        "fields": [],
        "statusCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
        "extendedErrorDetails": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "testname12",
    "phone": 2146354564,
    "seq": 7,
    "success": false,
    "created": false,
    "id": null,
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Use one of these records?",
        "fields": [],
        "statusCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
        "extendedErrorDetails": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "testname255",
    "phone": 12312,
    "seq": 8,
    "success": false,
    "created": false,
    "id": null,
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Use one of these records?",
        "fields": [],
        "statusCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
        "extendedErrorDetails": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "testname123",
    "phone": 211221,
    "seq": 9,
    "success": false,
    "created": false,
    "id": null,
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Use one of these records?",
        "fields": [],
        "statusCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
        "extendedErrorDetails": null
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "testname2133",
    "phone": 10218550,
    "seq": 10,
    "success": false,
    "created": false,
    "id": null,
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Use one of these records?",
        "fields": [],
        "statusCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
        "extendedErrorDetails": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

So the order of output will be same in the order of input sequence. So i need to append two.json key values in the same order into one.json

Please suggest me how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(j1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(j2)

jsn = df1.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True).to_dict(orient='records')
```

Then save the jsn

```
with open ('merged_json.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(jsn, f, indent=4)
```

Here is a sample of the first 3 records

```
[
    {
        "name": "testname",
        "phone": 212121,
        "seq": 1,
        "created": true,
        "errors": [],
        "id": "123",
        "success": true
    },
    {
        "name": "testname1",
        "phone": 2146354564,
        "seq": 2,
        "created": true,
        "errors": [],
        "id": "12121",
        "success": true
    },
    {
        "name": "testname2",
        "phone": 12312,
        "seq": 3,
        "created": false,
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "Use one of these records?",
                "fields": [],
                "statusCode": "DUPLICATES_DETECTED",
                "extendedErrorDetails": null
            }
        ],
        "id": null,
        "success": false
    },
```

This should be the most efficient approach, read more [here](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6)

Comment: works perfect but one more answer posted. i need to know which will be efficient

Comment: in terms of efficiency `for` loops in python is always slower, updated

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```py
output = []
for a,b in zip(one_json, two_json):
    a.update(b)
    output.append(a)
print(output)
```

Comment: works perfect but one more answer posted. i need to know which will be efficient